# What weight should each frame have in motion blur?

Tags: graphics, video, blur

I am working on a game and would like to add motion blur to videos that I export from the engine. Right now, I play back gameplay at 1/16th the original speed, giving me 16x more frames (e.g. instead of 60 frames per second, it's 960 frames per second) and averaging the frames. I am curious though, is this the proper weight or should I give frame samples closer to the middle more alpha? Also, should the frames sampled be sampled uniformly?

Comment: Motion around the edges of the screen should blur just like motion in the middle of the screen; uniform sampling from each frame makes sense. Unless you want physically-correct motion blur (which is far from trivial to implement yourself), I would think your approach is good enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to rethink motion blur and only do it for one frame, not blending between several. This will help you avoid a lot of edge cases where your frame rate is stuttering and you have to decide on which frames to blend and how much.

A common way to do this is using motion vectors, where you render your scene again, with extra data for each mesh, and render screen space velocity into a separate buffer. This buffer can then be used as a blur direction control. to compose the final blurred image.

You can also build depth of field information at the same time using this technique.

Comment: I am using a fixed framerate and not in realtime. I am thinking that it will give me a higher quality render.

Comment: Sure it can, but at what cost? If you have the power to jitter everything in time it might be good. Sorry if I did not answer your question.

Comment: You can probably look at some rayt racing papers for solutions for this. They usually blend jittered images, both in time and space.

Comment: @void I'm just not sure what weight I give each image or if I just average them.

Comment: Usually there is no "right" thing. Only what's looking good ;) Do you need physically correct blur? If not then you can probably use some heuristic to blend it. Tried using a bell curve? does it look bad if you just blend everything together with 1/16 the alpha each?

Comment: I haven't actually got that far yet, right now I've got it rendering in slow motion. Next I gotta blend and output to video. Also, I found this: http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/graphics/x_motion.htm